# Google function to request an API using python?

Tags: python, function, google-cloud-platform, python-requests

I have trying to request info from external website through API using Python in Google Cloud function and it’s always give me an error that something went wrong.

The code is:

```
import requests

def api_request(request):
    # URL of the API you want to request
    api_url = 'https://api.example.com/endpoint'

    # Make the API request
    response = requests.get(api_url)

    # Check the response status code
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        # Process the data or perform any desired operations
        # ...

        # Return a response
        return 'API request successful'
    else:
        return 'API request failed'

# Entry point for the Cloud Function
def main(request):
    return api_request(request)
```

I specified python library in requirements:

```
requests==2.26.0
```

Please any suggestions?

I am trying to request API from external website using Google Cloud functions in Python/requests library. I never was able to.

I tested my account with "hello world" function and it worked smoothly, which mean there is no problem with the account setting.

Comment: It’s already api_request

Comment: def main(request): return api_request(request) `
Please could you explain more?

Answer (score 0):

Entry point for your Cloud Function should be 'api_request'

Then run the code:

```
import requests
from google.cloud import bigquery

def api_request(request):
    # URL of the API you want to request
    api_url = 'https://api.example.com/endpoint'

    # Make the API request
    response = requests.get(api_url)

    # Check the response status code
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        # Process the data or perform any desired operations
        # ...

        # Return a response
        return 'API request successful'
    else:
        return 'API request failed'
```

python library in requirements:

```
google-cloud-bigquery==3.4.0
requests==2.26.0
```